# Cannot change mutable array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Ok so I have been stuck on this for a while even though it's a simple problem, I am trying to add an NSDictionary to an array however when calling the addObject method on the array the program crashes claiming I am sending a mutating method to an immutable object.

my code looks like:

```
    - (IBAction)btnSaveMessage:(id)sender {
        //Save The Message and Clear Text Fields

        NSMutableDictionary *newMessageDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [newMessageDictionary setObject:@"plist test title" forKey:@"Title"];
        [newMessageDictionary setObject:@"plist subtitle" forKey:@"Subtitle"];
        [newMessageDictionary setObject:@"-3.892119" forKey:@"Longitude"];
        [newMessageDictionary setObject:@"54.191707" forKey:@"Lattitude"];

        NSMutableArray *messagesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //Load Plist into array
        NSString *messagesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Messages"                 
        ofType:@"plist"];
        messagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:messagesPath];

        [messagesArray addObject:newMessageDictionary]; //this causes crash

        //write messagesarray to file

        NSString *plistPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,                 
            NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        plistPath = [plistPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"usersMessages.plist"];
        [messagesArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

So I understand that I am trying to add to what the compiler see's as an immutable array but I declared it as Mutable?

Whats going on? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-initializing messagesArray with

```
[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:messagesPath]
```

Making it not mutable.  Try:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:messagesPath];
```

Comment: You just needed someone to be your cocker spaniel.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your `NSMutableArray` with an `NSArray` in this line

```
messagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:messagesPath];
```

The class method `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` is returning just an `NSArray` and not an `NSMutableArray`.

If you want the content of the file mutable you can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *messagesArray = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:messagesPath] mutableCopy];
```

and you can remove the previous declaration

```
 NSMutableArray *messagesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

now.